# ASP / SQL - Dates being echoed different to what the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have a simple sql script in my classic ASP which is as follows

```
sql = "SELECT date FROM sales WHERE userid=1"
Set RS = Conn.Execute(sql)

date = RS.Fields("date")

Response.Write date
```

This is a broken down version, it works, but the results are different.

Im looking at the database using SQL Server and it is showing me

```
2014-10-05 15:06:00
```

But when the Response.Write runs, it is displaying it as

```
10/5/2014 3:06:00 PM
```

How can i use Response.Write to display it exactly as it is in the database?

Cheers,

Comment: I realize this is probably just sample code and the actual variable names are probably different, but please keep in mind that `Date` is a reserved word in VBScript - it's the function that returns today's date. VBScript will allow you to overload it, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
sql = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), date, 120) as date FROM sales WHERE userid=1"
```